# Extracting all possible ngrams in R tm document term matrix

Tags: r, tokenize, tm, n-gram, rweka

I am using the "tm" package in R to create a term document matrix. Then I use "RWeka" to extract trigrams as specified in the code below

```
myCorpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(reddata$Tweet))

#create tokenizer function
TriTok<- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 3, max = 3))
tdm <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus,control=list(tokenize=TriTok))
```

The problem here is that RWeka seemingly just goes through the list of terms and splits after every three words to get trigrams. 
For example the sentence:

```
 On hot summer days I enjoy eating ice cream
```

would be split into

```
"On hot summer"    "days I enjoy"    "eating ice cream"
```

But for example the phrase

```
"hot summer days"
```

would be ignored. Is there a way to get RWeka to include all trigrams or is there another option?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I apply your `TriTok` function to your phrase, it returns `"On hot summer"    "hot summer days"  "summer days I"    "days I enjoy"    
"I enjoy eating"   "enjoy eating ice" "eating ice cream"`so I'm wondering if the problem is elsewhere. Do you have example data?

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing this out. Went through my code again. I was just too stupid to realise that I had passed the wrong argument to DocumentTermMatrix( control = ). Instead of the TriTok generated by RWeka I was using a custom function.

Comment: Oh believe me, I've been there. Glad you sorted it!